# Export themes from my site?

Tags: 7, theming, importing-exporting, backups

Someone gave me access to a website of theres, and they want me to export the theme from one Drupal 7 install to another.

(I couldn't find any export links on the */admin/appearance* page.)

#### How do I export a theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have access to the web servers folder structure. You will find the themes inside sites/all/themes, sites/default/themes, sites/YOURSITE/themes or profiles/YOURPROFILE/themes. Once copied to the other Drupal installation it can be enabled under admin/appearance. [More on installing a Drupal theme can be found here.](http://drupal.org/getting-started/install-contrib/themes)

It might be that the theme you are going to copy is a subtheme of another theme. In this case you need both themes. Look inside the THEMENAME.info in your theme and look for the line that starts with base theme =

If a base theme is defined there you need that as well on your target installation.

Comment: Ended up received a `tar.gz` of the theme from the dev. Seems like an odd feature to leave out of Drupal... a simple export for these things

Comment: Also, if theme settings have changed you may also need to export the settings too. For this case you could use the **magic_dev** module which is part of http://drupal.org/project/magic module.